# Remove / change jquery code after resize device´s width

Tags: jquery, css

Hello i have got appearing (if scrolltop 100+) and disappearing (if scrolltop 100-) navbar. It works, but there is a one problem.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(document).scrollTop() >= 100) {
                $("#navbar1").animate({"opacity":"1"}, "fast");
                $("#main").animate({paddingTop: "70px"}, "fast");
            }else {
                $("#navbar1").animate({"opacity":"0"}, "fast");
                $("#main").animate({paddingTop: "20px"}, "fast");
            }
        });
```

On small devices like mobiles or tablets it takes too much time to appear and disappear (e.g. you are already on 500 px but navbar haven´t appeared yet), so i would want to use something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 780 px) {
    #navbar1 {
        opacity:1;
    }
    #main {
        padding-top:70px;
    }
}
```

But there is still same problem, i would like to have navbar appeared always if max-width: 780 px... is there any way to do it? Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing as it stands you might want to clarify with pictures or something

Comment: The JavaScript/jQuery code will override any CSS styles you have defined.  Could you modify `$(document).scrollTop() >= 100)` to something like `$(document).scrollTop() >= 100 || $(window).width() <= 780)`?

Comment: @arcyqwerty Thank you! You instilled me an idea. I just changed my jquery, appear and disappear only if min width = 780 and scrolltop = 100, else if the max width of device is 780, it is there by loaded page. I just founded what i wanted, cannot explain it bettter sorry. Thank you guys. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).width() > 780)){
                if($(document).scrollTop() >= 100) {
                    $("#navbar1").animate({"opacity":"1"}, "fast");
                    $("#main").animate({paddingTop: "70px"}, "fast");
                }else {
                    $("#navbar1").animate({"opacity":"0"}, "fast");
                    $("#main").animate({paddingTop: "20px"}, "fast");
                }
         }
    });
```

So, basically the same, but making the animation only when screens have over 780px, on the rest you can paint it with normal css styles